# knitr texmaker could not start the command

Tags: texmaker, mactex, mac, knitr

I have recently upgraded to El Capitan and I can't make knitr work with texmaker anymore. I have red all the issue concerning MacTex and the change in the path from `/usr` to `/Library/Tex` but here I can't figure out what is happening.

I have set up a knitr command : `Rscript -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"` but texmaker refuses to run it. When I copy and paste the error message into the terminal it works fine so there is no typo error. I don't understand what's going on!

Comment: @noname Not a Mac user, but do run knitr with texmaker in Windows.  Suggestion.  verify that you can run that specific command Rscript -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"  with the replacement of the % with an existing (in the current folder) Rnw file.  If you cannot run it from a command shell, then the problem is one of paths in the operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the comment it makes me look  onto Rscript localisation, and then finally fix the bug ! I add the anwser below

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to specify the full path to the `Rscript` command and to modify the `.Rprofile` file as well to add latex to your R session:

- in texmaker I have now `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/Rscript -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')"` (this is default location on Mac, but you can get yours by typing `R.home()` in a R session)
- in my `.Rprofile` I used the solution from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590134/why-is-knitr-unable-to-find-framed-sty-or-kpsewhich) post, ie I write `Sys.setenv("PATH" = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),"/Library/TeX/texbin",sep=":"))` (the `.Rprofile` is a hidden file on `/Users/my_user_name` directory`)

Hope this can help !